# Cannot share calendars with out having both email accts on Android phone

Tags: applications, calendar

I am trying to have a shared calendar with my wife.  It works great on the PC. but not on our android phones.  The only way I have been able to share calendars is by putting her email address in the my google mail app. But then I get her mail!

Just want to share calendars - not emails

Or, is there a way to have her gmail acct on my phone but somehow block her emails from my phone?

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do to share a calendar.

Comment: I share a gmail calendar on my PC with my wife - we see both of our events in the same view.  I want to do the same on my phone.  On my phone the only way I have been able to do this is by adding my wife's account to my list of email accounts.  The problem is that I get her emails too.  I just want to see both of our events on the phone.  Any thoughts very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First there's this, from the Help page at https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37082?hl=en

Emphasis is mine.

> You can share the main calendar for your account, or another calendar you created.
>
> 1. On your computer, open Google Calendar. ***You can't share calendars from the Google Calendar app.***
> 2. On the left, find the "My calendars" section. You might need to click it to expand it.
> 3. Hover over the calendar you want to share, click More More and then Settings and sharing.
> 4. To share with individuals: Under "Share with specific people," add the person or the email address of the person you want to share with.
> 5. To change wider sharing settings: Under "Access permissions," choose an option in the drop-down menu. Learn more about these options below.
> 6. If someone isn't already added, click Add people.
> 7. Add people and click Send.
>
> If you shared your calendar with an individual email address, they'll see your calendar in their "Other calendars" list. If you shared your calendar with an email group , they'll see the calendar in their "Other calendars" list once they click on the link in the email invitation from Google Calendar.

Then there's this: https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37100?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en

> Add using Email Address
>
> Ask to see a calendar
>
> 1. On your computer, open Google Calendar. You can only edit Google Calendar sharing settings from a computer, not the app.
> 2. On the left side, click Other calendars.
> 3. In the Add a friend's calendar or Add a coworker's calendar box, enter the other person's email address.
> 4. Press Enter.
> 5. Depending on how their calendar is shared, one of the following will happen:
>
>    - If the calendar isn't shared with you, you'll see a form to request access.
>    - If the calendar is already shared with you, their calendar will be added on the left side under "Other calendars."
>    - If the other person doesn't have a Google Calendar, you'll see the option to invite them to use Google Calendar.
>
> Approval by the other person
>
> If their calendar isn't shared with you, the other person will get an email requesting access.
>
> To accept your request, the other person should:
>
> 1. On your computer, open the email you sent requesting access.
> 2. Click the link in the email.
> 3. In the Settings page that opens, choose a permission setting and select Add Person.
> 4. Click Save.
>
> After the other person has accepted your request, their calendar will appear on the left side under "Other calendars." If you don't see it, try refreshing the page.

Comment: Thank you.

Is there a way to have the spouses email on the droid phone and NOT see her emails?

Comment: If there was, that's the answer I would have given. As you can see, that's not the case.